# Define Azure APIM Definitions in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

For a project I'm working on, I need to define an entire Azure APIM in Bicep.
Now I want to define the request/response definitions for the developer portal, see the attached screenhot.

I've tried looking through the Azure documentation but found nothing to define these using Bicep. I have also tried exporting the APIM to ARM JSON, converting it to Bicep using `az bicep decompile --file template.json`, and reverse-engineering the definitions but the contents of the field `Schema` aren't included in the export output.

Does anyone know how to define the definitions in Bicep?

[image]

Comment: Please have look here: https://vinniejames.medium.com/bicep-automate-deployment-of-api-management-and-its-components-26e4b8aee28

Comment: Unfortunately, the article did not contain what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define an schema sub-resource as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis/schemas then use the schema’s resourceID in operations’ schemaId property.

Comment: Defining the schemas works as intended. Mapping them to the operation doesn't work like that and I will post another question.